# Yii2 understanding dataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

There are 2 statuses `ORDER_PAID` and `ORDER_DELIVERED` and i need to display 5 blocks on the page with following datasets:

1. Total sum of orders: 
   Each item in database has field sum, that I need to count.
2. Sum of orders with status `ORDER_PAID`
3. Sum of orders with status `ORDER_DELIVERED`
4. A graph that displays the correlation between orders with `ORDER_PAID` and `ORDER_DELIVERED` statuses
5. Table that contains **only** orders with `ORDER_PAID` status.

All the above depends on data that is selected by user (between to dates, last week, last month). There are also 4 request

`getOrderDeliveredSum()` + `getOrderPaidSum()` = `getTotal()`

For example I have function that :

```
function getOrderPaidSum(){
         return Orders::find()
                ->where(["owned" => \Yii::$app->user->id])
                ->andWhere(["status.code" => "ORDER_PAID"])
                ->sum();
    }
```

And also `getOrdersContext` that fetchs data for graph\table:

```
function getOrdersContext($params){

    $query = Orders::find()
        ->where(["owned" => \Yii::$app->user->id])
        ->orderBy('id DESC');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if(!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())){
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But as you can see there are request that fetches the same data but for different purpose. Is there any optimization opportunities?

**UPD 1**
I want to get next values from my db:

1. The total sum of orders for current user.
2. To get the total sum of orders for current user I have to calculate order's sums with statuses `ORDER_PAID` and `ORDER_DELIVERED`
3. I also use `Highcharts::widget` and `GridView::widget` to display the data. (It's a sortable table that contains orders with status `ORDER_PAID` and a graph that displays price for each order with `ORDER_DELIVERED` and `ORDER_PAID`.

Comment: The explaination of your question is not clear to me .. could you post a sample and the result you need ?

Comment: @scaisEdge, I've added section `UPD 1`. Please, check it.

Comment: OK .. a few better  .. Looking to your code .. eg the function getOrderPaidSum()  i don't understand why  you need al the models instead of the simple sum result .. seems you want all the models for calculate the sum in php .. .. But the correct approach for me should be different ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Well, it seems that I failed to explain. I have one table called `orders` that contains all the stuff. I don't know how to prepare data. The problem is that I have to separate the result by statuses `ORDER_DELIVERED` and `ORDER_PAID`

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is calculate the two sum you  need separately

```
myTotalPaid  = Orders::find()
            ->where(["owned" => \Yii::$app->user->id])
            ->andWhere(["status.code" => "ORDER_PAID"])
            ->sum('my_column_for_sum');


myTotalDelivered  = Orders::find()
            ->where(["owned" => \Yii::$app->user->id])
            ->andWhere(["status.code" => "ORDER_DELIVERED"])
            ->sum('my_column_for_sum');
```

then obtain the data Provider for ORDER_PAID

```
$query = Orders::find()
            ->where(["owned" => \Yii::$app->user->id])
            ->andWhere(["status.code" => "ORDER_PAID"])
            ->orderBy('id DESC');

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```